# mysql count distinct num using with statment on too many rows

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, case

I have a table with many order record and each record has a column named phone used to indicate a user.

What I want to do is to count the distinct phone number in some date range. And my sql is like
the follows:

```
select count(distinct phone),
count(distinct case when order_date < '2013-1-19' then phone end)
from some_table
where order_date >= '2013-1-1' and order_date < '2013-2-1'
```

and the result is strange:

```
194410  0
```

The statement `count(distinct case when order_date < '2013-1-19' then phone end)` got a result of ZERO! However, when I manually checked the result using the following sql:

```
select count(distinct phone)
from some_table
where order_date >= '2013-1-1' and order_date < '2013-1-19'
```

I was informed that there is 171300 distinct phone meeting than condition.

And if I reduce the date range to [2013-1-1, 2013-1-16) in `count(distinct case when order_date < '2013-1-19' then phone end)`, I got the right result. And there is only 161415 distinct phone this time.

What's wrong with my first sql?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `COUNT(DISTINCT phone)` or `GROUP BY phone` first and `COUNT()` in an outer select to get distinct values.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT phone) total
   FROM orders
  WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' 
                       AND '2013-05-07'
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM (SELECT phone
          FROM orders
         WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' 
                              AND '2013-05-07'
         GROUP BY phone) q
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4856c/8)**

**UPDATE**: If I understand your comment correctly you can always do following

```
SELECT total1, total2, total1-total2 total3
FROM(SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT phone) 
   FROM orders
  WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' 
                       AND '2013-05-07') total1, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT phone) 
   FROM orders
  WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' 
                       AND '2013-05-04') total2) n
```

Output:

```
| TOTAL1 | TOTAL2 | TOTAL3 |
----------------------------
|      4 |      2 |      2 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4856c/11)**

Comment: Your solution only calculate the distinct phone number between 2013-5-1 and 2013-5-7. However, I Want both the distinct phone number in [2013-5-1, 2-13-5-7] and [2013-5-1, 2013-6-1].

Comment: @jlyu Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the count of distinct phone numbers within the date range, you do not need the second count, only the first.

I may have misunderstood your question, though. If so, I am sorry, and please explain what I am missing and I'll try to help.

Best wishes,

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. What I want to is calculate the phone number net growth. First, I calculate the distinct phone number during date 2013-1-1 and 2013-1-31. Then, I calculate the distinct phone number during date 2013-1-1 and 2013-1-18. Last, the net growth will be calculated by the subtraction of the value obtained by during first and second step.

Comment: @jlyu Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: @jlyu - peterm has answered your question adequately, if I understood it correctly. Upvoted!